# Second end of a Catenary of known length passing through a point and intersecting two straight lines at a known distance.

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, arc-length

I have the coordinates of one extreme point $D=(0,y_D)$, two lines $y = m_ix + y_D$ for $i\in \{ A,B \}$ intersecting the catenary at two point $A$ and $B$, and also in $D$. I know the length $L_{DA}$ of the catenary from $D$ to $A$, $L_{AB}$ from $A$ to $B$ and the overall length $L_{DE}$ from $D$ to $E$.
I want to find the coordinates of the second extreme point $E$, as per the [linked picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlVYR.jpg) ($L = L_{AB}$).

My understanding is that given these conditions (one point, two intersections and a known distance between the intersections) the solution must be unique.
My approach would be to find the equation of the catenary and then locate $E$, $L_{DE}$ away from the starting point $D$ along the curve.

I know that there is probably no analytical solution, as this involves a transcendental function. The equations I derived read as follows:

The shape of the catenary is expressed as $$y = c + a \cosh\left(\frac{x-b}{a}\right),$$

where $a,b,c$ are unknown. Three lengths are known

$$ L_{AB} = \int_{x_A}^{x_B} \cosh\left(\frac{t-b}{a}\right)dt = a\left[\sinh\left(\frac{x_B -b}{a}\right) - \sinh\left(\frac{x_A -b}{a}\right)\right] $$
$$ L_{DA} = \ldots = a\left[\sinh\left(\frac{x_A -b}{a}\right) - \sinh\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right)\right],$$
$$ L_{DE} = \ldots = a\left[\sinh\left(\frac{x_E -b}{a}\right) - \sinh\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right)\right],$$
and the two lines intersect the catenary
$$y_A = c + a \cosh\left(\frac{x_A-b}{a}\right) = m_A x_A + y_D$$
$$y_B = c + a \cosh\left(\frac{x_B-b}{a}\right) = m_B x_B + y_D$$

I have looked at similar problems, such as [Finding points along a catenary curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599002/finding-points-along-a-catenary-curve?newreg=ed242129225442649816853258ff8922), but I do not know how to reduce this problem to that one. It seems to me the two coincide, once the coordinates $(x_A,y_A)$ or $(x_B, y_B)$ have been fixed.
Is it possible to obtain a similar solution (*i.e.* analytically driven, but for the solution of the transcendental equation) or an algorithm to approximate the coordinates of $E$?

Comment: Again, *Welcome to the site !* Now, this is a good question and $\to +1$.

Comment: I have the feeling that you face a difficult problem. Would you be able to solve if for a parabola instead of a catenary ? It yes, it would provide good estimates for an optimization.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I was unable to obtain an analytical solution for the parabola case.
I tried with numerical optimization, by iterating, from an initial guess of $a$ and $b$:
- find numerically the intersections between the lines and the catenary $x_A, x_B$
- calculate an error as the difference between their distance along the catenary and the known distance $L$
It seems that this solutions is really not robust though: many local minima exist, i.e. there are many catenaries that cross 2 lines forming 2 crossings with a certain distance $L$ or similar.

Comment: What was the objective function ? I am interested by tis problem. Could you give me a set of values to try some ideas ? By the way, I worked at your place in Milano .... 50 years ago !!

Comment: Probably it's not rigorous, but I wrote a cost function that, given $a,b$, finds the intersections with the lines with Newton's method, inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068912/solving-sinhax-bx). I then use the formula in the question to calculate the length between intersections and the error I minimize is the difference between that and the known actual length $L$.
For my experiments I used ad _real_ values: $y_D=3$, $m_A= -0.5$, $m_B=-0.3$, $a=1.2$, $b = 1.8$. As a consequence $L = 0.5773$.
I can share my Matlab code if you want (contact me in private, please).

Comment: Update: I have found a satisfying numerical solution, by adding to the cost function another term: the error between the estimated and known distance along the catenary of points $D$ and $A$. I did not initially state that this parameter is also known, I will update the question.
I will describe the solution in more detail in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem can be solved as a single optimization problem using as only variables $a$ and $b$

The coordinates of the points are
$$x_A \qquad\qquad y_A=y_D+a \cosh \left(\frac{x_A-b}{a}\right)-a \cosh \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$
$$x_B \qquad\qquad y_B=y_D+a \cosh \left(\frac{x_B-b}{a}\right)-a \cosh \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$
$$x_E \qquad\qquad y_E=y_D+a \cosh \left(\frac{x_E-b}{a}\right)-a \cosh \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$

We also have
$$y_A=y_D+m_A\,x_A \qquad\text{and}\qquad y_B=y_D+m_B\, x_B$$ So, the five equations are
$$\text{Equa}_1=a \cosh \left(\frac{x_A-b}{a}\right)-a \cosh \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)-m_A \,x_A=0\tag 1$$
$$\text{Equa}_2=a \cosh \left(\frac{x_B-b}{a}\right)-a \cosh \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)-m_B \,x_B=0\tag 2$$
$$\text{Equa}_3=a\sinh\left(\frac{x_B -b}{a}\right) - a\sinh\left(\frac{x_A -b}{a}\right)-L_{AB}=0\tag 3$$
$$\text{Equa}_4=a\sinh\left(\frac{x_A -b}{a}\right)+ a\sinh\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)-L_{DA}=0\tag 4$$
$$\text{Equa}_5=a\sinh\left(\frac{x_E -b}{a}\right)+ a\sinh\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)-L_{DE}=0\tag 5$$

Using $(4)$ and $(5)$ we have
$$x_A=b+a \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{L_{DA}}{a}-\sinh \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)\tag 6$$
$$x_E=b+a \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{L_{DE}}{a}-\sinh \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)\tag 7$$

Using $(3)$
$$x_B=b+a \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sinh \left(\frac{x_A-b}{a}\right)+\frac{L_{AB}}{a}\right)\tag 8$$

So $(x_A,x_B,x_E)$ are explicit functions of $(a,b,L_{AB},L_{DA},L_{DE})$

So, consider the norm
$$\Phi(a,b)=\big[\text{Equa}_1\big]^2+\big[\text{Equa}_2\big]^2$$ and minimize it with respect to $a$ and $b$.

**Edit**

I made a test run using
$$m_A=-\frac 12 \quad m_B=-\frac 3{10}\quad L_{AB}=\frac{5773}{10000}\quad L_{DA}=\frac{34621}{10000}\quad L_{DE}=\frac{55743}{5000}$$ and the results are
$$a=1.199971086\qquad b=1.799969533\qquad \implies \qquad \Phi \sim 0$$ which leads to $x_E=4.999926081$.

**Update**

As I wrote in comments, it would be better to consider as independant variables $a$ and $k=\frac ba$. Doing so, we can divide $(1)$ and $(2)$ by $a$ and have
$$m_A\Bigg[k+\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{L_{DA}}{a}-\sinh (k)\right) \Bigg]+\cosh(k)-\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{L_{DA}}{a}-\sinh (k)\right)^2}=0 \tag {1a}$$ and a similar one to make $(2a)$

Comment: Thanks, this works. It is more elegant than the one i proposed, as it does not rely on the estimation of $x_A$ and $x_B$ with Newton's method. It also seems to converge to the correct solution more easily, given different initial conditions.
I would also note that equations $(5)$ and $(7)$ are not strictly necessary to solve the optimization problem, _i.e._ the length $L_{DE}$ is superfluous. On the other hand, $(7)$ easily identifies where the endpoint is, if $L_{DE}$ is finite.
I would upvote the answer, but I don't have enough reputation...

Comment: @MicheleBolognini. I wonder if it would not be better to consider as variables $a$ and $k=\frac b a$ to make them independant.

Comment: Do you think this would make for a better optimization?

Comment: @MicheleBolognini. I wrote an update. Using $a$ and $k=\frac b a$ is incredibly better in terms of stability and robustness. Thanks for this nice problem.

Comment: The second equation should then look something like $ m_B\left[ k + \sinh^{-1}\left( \frac{L_{DA}}{a} -\sinh\left(k\right)+\frac{L_{AB}}{a} \right)\right] + \cosh\left(k\right) - \sqrt{1+\left[\frac{L_{DA}}{a} - \sinh\left(k\right) + \frac{L_{AB}}{a}\right]^2}$

Answer (score 0):

I found at least a numerical solution to the problem. I use a nonlinear, constrained optimizer to minimize an error cost function of the parameters $a$, $b$.
Given that the catenary must go through $(0, y_D)$, parameter $c$ is a function of $a$ and $b$:
$$ c = y_D - a \cosh\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right).$$

The error cost function $e$ is nonlinear, and is the sum of the norms of the errors between the known and estimated distances of $D$ and $A$ and of $A$ and $B$ along the catenary. Using the equations in the question text and recalling that $x_D=0$ by definition:

$$e = || a\left(\sinh\left(\frac{x_B-b}{a}\right) - \sinh\left(\frac{x_A-b}{A}\right)\right) - L_{AB}|| + ||a\left(\sinh\left(\frac{x_A-b}{a}\right) - \sinh\left(\frac{-b}{A}\right)\right) - L_{DA}||.$$

At each call of the cost function, with a new pair of parameters $a$ and $b$,   $x_A$ and $x_B$ are calculated numerically by solving
$$c + a \cosh\left(\frac{x_A-b}{a}\right) = m_A x_A + y_D$$
with Newton's method, as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068912/solving-sinhax-bx).
Upper and lower bounds for optimization variables $a$ and $b$ depend on the application.
Furthermore, I suggest to pick the initial guess $a_0, b_0$ as an underestimate of what the values are going to be. In my experience, the optimization problem tends to converge to the correct solution more easily this way.
The cost function is highly non-linear, therefore convergence depends (also) on the initial guess.

Answer (score 0):

If I did not miss something, the following:

Arc lengths (DA,DB,DE) measured from D are given. Coordinates of (A,B,E) should be found. Lines connecting D to them may be drawn as a last (avoidable) step.

If we find the differential equation of all Catenaries passing through D we notice that there is no unique determination of coordinates.. but can be found upto constants of integration.

[image]

The Catenary ode can be derived *intrinsic*:

Catenary property $ y \cos \phi = c$
is differentiated w.r.t. arc and simplified.

$$ \frac{d \phi}{ds}= \frac{\cos^{2}\phi}{c}\; ;$$
Integrating

$$ \tan \phi = \frac{s-s_{min}}{c} \; ; $$

in terms of slope $\phi$, arc length s, arc-length $s_{min}$ at minimum ordinate c. Else this is also obtained by differentiating

$$ y= c \cosh \frac{x-C_2}{c}. $$

There would be as many solutions as the number of assumptions for admissible initial slopes $\phi_{D}.$ If $c$ is also varied then there is a *doubly infinite set* of solutions.

In other words, each Catenary can be bent to  any other of the Catenary set passing through D. Some cases can be numerically calculated and plotted if so desired by the OP.

This can be *physically* demonstrated using a flexible chain suspended at D and having (A,B,E) points marked at given arc distances.

EDIT1

*`Mathematica`* platform numerically computed Catenaries with varying arc lengths, two initial slopes at D = (- 0.85,-1.12).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Narasimham, but I think your solution lacks one detail from the question text: points $A$ and $B$ also lie on a straight line passing through $D$ and having a known length. This is what reduces the number of correct solutions to 1.
I think it is apparent from the linked figure, which I do not have enough reputation to post in the question directly.