# How to find minimum point of a hanging rope with two fixed known points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ and known length?

Tags: numerical-methods, problem-solving

I need to find minimum point of hanging rope with two known points $p_1, p_2$ (start and end point of the rope) and known rope length.

I want to model all rope shapes with different length and start and end point.

Do I have to use numerical methods?

Does it have any closed form solution?

Known $\to L,(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ then $a=$?

I use a general catenary equation like below:

$$
f(x)= a\cosh\left(\frac {x-b}a\right)+c\\
L= a\sinh\left(\frac{x_2}{a}\right)-a\sinh\left(\frac{x_1}{a}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @Cesareo answer, considering
$$L^2-v^2 = 4a^2\sinh^2\left(\frac{h}{2a}\right)$$ let $x=\frac{h}{2a}$ to make the equation
$$\frac{L^2-v^2}{h^2}=\frac{\sinh^2(x) }{x^2}\implies k=\sqrt{\frac{L^2-v^2}{h^2}}=\frac{\sinh(x) }{x}$$

Consider that you look for the zero of $$f(x)=\frac{\sinh(x) }{x}-k$$ It varies very quickly. Then, it would be better to look for the zero of
 $$g(x)=\log \left(\frac{\sinh (x)}{x}\right)-\log(k)$$ which is much better conditioned.

**Edit**

To get a starting value $x_0$ for Newton method, using Padé approximant built at $x=0$
$$\frac{\sinh (x)}x\simeq \frac{7 x^2+60}{60-3 x^2} \implies x_0=\frac{2 \sqrt{15} \sqrt{k-1}}{\sqrt{3 k+7}}$$ which would be good for $1 \leq k \leq 3$.

For larger values of $k$
$$\frac{\sinh (x)}x\simeq \frac{e^x}{2 x}\implies x_0=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 k}\right)$$ where appears Lambert function.

The table below shows some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & x_0 & x \\
 1.25 & 1.18125 &  1.18273 \\
 1.50 & 1.61515 &  1.62213 \\
 1.75 & 1.91663 &  1.93300 \\
 2.00 & 2.14834 &  2.17732 \\
 2.25 & 2.33550 &  2.37963 \\
 2.50 & 2.49136 &  2.55265 \\
 2.75 & 2.62398 &  2.70395 \\
 3.00 & 2.73861 &  2.83845 \\
      &         &          \\
 3.00 & 2.83315 &  2.83845 \\
 3.25 & 2.95545 &  2.95952 \\
 3.50 & 3.06642 &  3.06962 \\
 3.75 & 3.16801 &  3.17058 \\
 4.00 & 3.26169 &  3.26380 \\
 4.25 & 3.34861 &  3.35037 \\
 4.50 & 3.42970 &  3.43117 \\
 4.75 & 3.50567 &  3.50693 \\
 5.00 & 3.57715 &  3.57823   
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068912/solving-sinhax-bx/1068927#1068927) (which I did not remember - problem of age, I guess), I noticed that I was able to generate a quite good estimates building at $x=0$ the $[3,4]$ Padé approximant of $\sinh(x)-k x$.

From this, I considered building the $[3,2n]$ Padé approximants which write
$$\sinh(x)-k x=x \frac{(1-k)+a^{(n)}_1 x^2 }{1+\sum_{m=1}^n b_m x^{2m} }$$ leading to an approximate solution
$$x=\sqrt{\frac {k-1}{a^{(n)}_1 }}$$ For sure, this was done using a CAS. The longest result able to fit on a single line corresponds to $n=6$ and the result is
$$x=\frac{\sqrt{6} \sqrt{(k-1)(105 k^5+60705 k^4+1365738 k^3+5507466 k^2+5665509 k+1414477 )}}{\sqrt{3 k^6+6120 k^5+307017 k^4+2586544 k^3+5952621 k^2+4301640
   k+860055}}$$ which seems to be very good even for large values of $k$ (checked up to $k=500$).

Comment: Thanks. So I need to compute two newton methods?
one for computing a and the other one for computing b?
How can I compute W-1. I need iteration method again?

Comment: @Mahdi. There is only one Newton method. Depending on the value of $k$, you generate $x_0$ using one or the other formula. For the evalution of $W_{-1}(.)$ have a look at the expansions given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 0):

Calling

$$
x_2-x_1 = h\\
y_2-y_1 = v
$$

we have

$$
v = a\cosh\left(\frac{x_2}{a}\right)-a\cosh\left(\frac{x_1}{a}\right)\\
L = a\sinh\left(\frac{x_2}{a}\right)-a\sinh\left(\frac{x_1}{a}\right)
$$

so after some trigonometric transformations we arrive at

$$
L^2-v^2 = 4a^2\sinh^2\left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{2a}\right)
$$

so we have finally

$$
L^2-v^2 = 4a^2\sinh^2\left(\frac{h}{2a}\right)
$$

with this last equation we can determine the $a = a_0$ value using an iterative procedure.

NOTE

Calling now

$$
y(x) = y_0 + a_0\cosh\left(\frac{x-x_0}{a_0}\right)
$$

such that

$$
y(x_1) = y_1\\
y(x_2) = y_2
$$

The minimum point is obtained by solving for $x$

$$
y'(x) = 0
$$

so if $x_1 \le x_0 \le x_2$ follows

$$
\min y(x) = y_0 + a_0
$$

otherwise

$$
\min y(x) = \min(y_1, y_2)
$$

Now, regarding the iterative process we have

$$
\frac{L^2-v^2}{4a^2} = \sinh^2\left(\frac{h}{2a}\right)
$$

or

$$
C_0^2\lambda^2=\sinh^2\lambda,\ \ \lambda = \frac{h}{2a},\ \ C_0 = \frac{\sqrt{L^2-v^2}}{h}
$$

or

$$
C_0 \lambda = \sinh(\lambda)
$$

which should be solved numerically.

Comment: Thanks. So I need iterative methods.

Comment: Excuse me. My equation is general form of catenary like below: y=a*cosh((x-x0)/a)+y0. I want all catenary shapes not just symmetrical shapes. I would like to model all ropes with different start, end points and length. I changed my question.How can I compute x0,y0 with respect to two equations. I need to use numerical computation or analytical? Thanks.